# lookup domain name from ip address

Tags: networking, dns, ip

I am trying to understand how a DNS work. My limited understanding is that the mapping of Static ip and domain name is 1-1.

By doing a whois query
broadcom.com -> 68.142.68.26

look up ip
68.142.68.26 -> broadcom.com

however, this is not the behaviour when i use https://whois.domaintools.com

querying broadcom.com will give me the ip address 68.142.68.26

However, when i query 68.142.68.26, the organization owner is Limelight Networks ARIN Admin

This is also true to other domains that i query such as [www.cravath.com](http://www.cravath.com), where the ip owner is listed as clourflare.

is there a way to get a 1-1 mapping?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Whois is not related to DNS. Results may be completely non-coherent.

Translating an IP address to a hostname is done using the DNs *PTR* record. For 68.142.68.26, you'd query the PTR for `26.68.142.68.in-addr.arpa`.

You might get something completely different than the hostname you resolved to an IP address (per *A* record) to begin with. This is completely normal, many different hostnames can point to a single IP (think of multiple virtual HTTP servers on a single physical host, for instance).

*Whois* queries a database to find the *owner* of a certain IP address. That might be something entirely different yet. E.g. an ISP is the owner of an address (per *whois*), but rents it out to a web hoster (owner of the PTR domain) who rents virtual servers to end customers (the hostname you started with).